# Is there any difference between 'in the control of " and "in control of"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, definite-articles

For example:

1. the terrorist is in the control of the government
2. the terrorist is in control of the goverment

Comment: Have you tried looking those two phrases up? (aka what research have you done on these two phrases?)

Comment: Yes I try to figure out the difference between them. I have some idea but not sure enough. In fact, it is related to the use of the article "the" in applied lingguistics. Personally, the first sentence probably means the government use its legitimate power to restrain the terrorist. The second may mean the government takes responsibility for the terorist. Right?

Comment: This might be better suited for the English Language Learners site, but I'm not sure

Comment: They mean exactly the opposite of each other.

Answer (score 1):

**X** is *in the control of* **Y** means that **Y** is controlling **X.**

**X** is *in control of* **Y** means that **X** is controlling **Y.**

So in your examples,

> the terrorist is in the control of the government

means that the government is controlling the terrorist, while

> the terrorist is in control of the government

means that the terrorist is controlling the government.